# Why output is blank when displaying return value of readFileSync on a file that is on a different dir, in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

The code below is for reading the contents of a file, info2.txt which stored in a separate directory called data. The data directory is in the same place as the js file which contains the code, hence the filepath I have as argument to readFileSync().

The console displays a blank output. I have tried transferring the .txt file to the same dir as the js file and it was able to display, and have also tried using the async alternative readdir(). But I need it to be in another directory, and it needs to be synchronous, as part of an exercise's instruction.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
try {
    
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./info.txt', 'utf8');
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./data/info2.txt', 'utf8');
    readStream.pipe(writeStream);
    
    
        let file = fs.readFileSync( './data/info2.txt', 'utf8');
        console.log(file.toString());

        
} catch (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Relative paths will be based on the app's root directory, not the directory a source file is in. There are a few ways this can be resolved; which makes the most sense depends on context.

Comment: `readStream.pipe(writeStream);` is asynchronous. You're trying to read the `info2.txt` file before it's fully written.